# Manim Overlaps Previous Frames

Tags: python, python-3.x, animation, video, manim

I was trying to make a chemistry animation using manim and everything was working fine until I it wasn't: The previous frames were "burning" on to the current one. The FadeOut animation wasn't working anymore. Here is my code:

```py
from manim import *

class RingExpansion(MovingCameraScene):
    def construct(self):
        template = TexTemplate()
        template.add_to_preamble("\\usepackage{chemfig}")
        st1 = Tex(r"""Internal angle of a regular polygon: $\theta=180\times\left(\frac{n-2}{n}\right)$""")
        self.play(Write(st1))
        self.wait()
        st1_shifted = st1.copy().shift(UP*3)
        self.play(Transform(st1, st1_shifted), lag_ratio=0.1, run_time=2)
        self.wait()
        st2 = Tex(r"""Angle strain = $109^\circ28'-\theta$""").shift(UP*2)
        self.play(Write(st2))
        self.wait()
        chem = Tex(r"\chemfig{*3([:-30]---)}", tex_template=template)
        chem.set_stroke(WHITE, 2)
        l1 = Tex(r"Angle Strain: $49^\circ28'$").next_to(chem, LEFT+DOWN*2)
        self.play(Write(chem))
        self.wait()
        self.play(Write(l1))
        self.wait()
        chem2 = Tex(r"\chemfig{*4(----)}", tex_template=template).next_to(chem, RIGHT*10)
        chem2.set_stroke(WHITE, 2)
        arrow12 =  Arrow(chem.get_center()+RIGHT, chem2.get_center()+LEFT, color=YELLOW)
        arrow12text = Tex(r"Ring Exp.").next_to(arrow12, UP)
        l2 = Tex(r"Angle Strain: $19^\circ28'$").next_to(chem2, DOWN*2)
        self.play(self.camera.frame.animate.move_to(chem2), TransformMatchingShapes(l1, l2), GrowArrow(arrow12), Write(arrow12text))
        self.play(Write(chem2))
        self.wait()
        chem3 = Tex(r"\chemfig{*5([:18]-----)}", tex_template=template).next_to(chem2, RIGHT*10)
        chem3.set_stroke(WHITE, 2)
        arrow23 =  Arrow(chem2.get_center()+RIGHT, chem3.get_center()+LEFT, color=YELLOW)
        arrow23text = Tex(r"Ring Exp.").next_to(arrow23, UP)
        l3 = Tex(r"Angle Strain: $1^\circ28'$").next_to(chem3, DOWN*2)
        self.play(self.camera.frame.animate.move_to(chem3), TransformMatchingShapes(l2, l3), GrowArrow(arrow23), Write(arrow23text))
        self.play(Write(chem3))
        self.wait()
        chem4 = Tex(r"\chemfig{*6(------)}", tex_template=template).next_to(chem3, RIGHT*10)
        chem4.set_stroke(WHITE, 2)
        arrow34 =  Arrow(chem3.get_center()+RIGHT, chem4.get_center()+LEFT, color=YELLOW)
        arrow34text = Tex(r"Ring Exp.").next_to(arrow34, UP)
        l4 = Tex(r"No Angle Strain").next_to(chem4, DOWN*2)
        self.play(self.camera.frame.animate.move_to(chem4), TransformMatchingShapes(l3, l4), GrowArrow(arrow34), Write(arrow34text))
        self.play(Write(chem4))
        self.wait()
        chem5 = Tex(r"\chemfig{*7([:12.8]-------)}", tex_template=template).next_to(chem4, RIGHT*12)
        chem5.set_stroke(WHITE, 2)
        arrow45 =  Arrow(chem4.get_center()+RIGHT*1.5, chem5.get_center()+LEFT*1.5, color=YELLOW)
        arrow45text = Tex(r"Ring Exp.").next_to(arrow45, UP)
        l5 = Tex(r"No Angle Strain").next_to(chem5, DOWN*2)
        self.play(self.camera.frame.animate.move_to(chem5), TransformMatchingShapes(l4, l5), GrowArrow(arrow45), Write(arrow45text))
        self.play(Write(chem5))
        self.wait()
        carrow54 = CurvedArrow(chem5.get_center()+LEFT*1.5+UP, chem4.get_center()+RIGHT*1.5+UP, color=BLUE_A)
        carrow54text = Tex(r"Driving Force").next_to(carrow54, UP)
        self.play(self.camera.frame.animate.move_to(chem4.get_center()), TransformMatchingShapes(l5, l4), Create(carrow54), Write(carrow54text))
        arrow54 = Arrow(chem5.get_center()+LEFT*1.5, chem4.get_center()+RIGHT*1.5, color=YELLOW)
        arrow54text = Tex(r"Ring Cont.").next_to(arrow54, UP)
        self.play(self.camera.frame.animate.move_to(arrow54), Transform(arrow45, arrow54), TransformMatchingShapes(arrow45text, arrow54text))
        self.wait()
        l6 = Tex(r"Most stable state").next_to(chem4, DOWN*2)
        self.play(self.camera.frame.animate.move_to(chem4), Transform(l4, l6))
        self.wait()


class Question1(MovingCameraScene):
    def construct(self):
        template = TexTemplate()
        template.add_to_preamble("\\usepackage{chemfig}")
        title = Tex("Write the most stable $C^\oplus$ formed after rearrangement")
        self.play(Write(title))
        self.play(Transform(title, title.copy().to_edge(UP), lag_ratio=0.1, run_time=2))
        self.wait()
        q1_s1 = Tex(r"\chemfig{*5([:18]---[@{sb1}]([:30]-\oplus@{pc1})([:150]-)--)}", tex_template=template).set_stroke(WHITE, 2)
        carrow1 = CurvedArrow(q1_s1[0][2].get_center(), q1_s1[0][3].get_center(), color=GREEN)
        carrow2 = CurvedArrow(q1_s1[0][4].get_center(), q1_s1[0][5].get_center(), color=RED)
        self.play(Write(q1_s1))
        self.wait()
        self.play(Write(carrow2))
        self.wait()
        self.play(FadeOut(carrow2))
        q1_s2 = Tex(r"""\chemfig{*5([:18]---\oplus(--[::60])--)}""", tex_template=template).shift(LEFT*3).set_stroke(WHITE, 2)
        q1_s3 = Tex(r"""\chemfig{*6(----\oplus(-)--)}""", tex_template=template).shift(RIGHT*3).set_stroke(WHITE, 2)
        q1_s1c = q1_s1.copy()
        self.add(q1_s1c)
        self.play(Transform(q1_s1, q1_s2))
        self.wait()
        self.play(Write(carrow1))
        self.wait()
        self.play(FadeOut(carrow1))
        self.play(Transform(q1_s1c, q1_s3))
        s2l = Tex("Unstable Product").next_to(q1_s2, DOWN)
        s3l = Tex("Most Stable Product").next_to(q1_s3, DOWN)
        self.play(Write(s2l), Write(s3l))
        self.wait()
        self.play(FadeOut(VGroup(q1_s2, s2l), shift=LEFT*2))
        self.play(VGroup(q1_s3, s3l).animate.shift(LEFT*3))
        self.wait()
        self.play(FadeOut(VGroup(q1_s3, s3l)))

        q1_s1 = Tex(r"\chemfig{*6(----([:30]-\oplus)([:150]-)--)}", tex_template=template).set_stroke(WHITE, 2)
        self.play(Write(q1_s1))
        self.wait()
        q1_s2 = Tex(r"\chemfig{*5([:18]---\oplus(--[::60])--)}", tex_template=template).shift(LEFT*3).set_stroke(WHITE, 2)
        q1_s3 = Tex(r"\chemfig{*7([:-12.8]-----(-\oplus)--)}", tex_template=template).set_stroke(WHITE, 2).shift(RIGHT*3)
        carrow1 = CurvedArrow(q1_s1[0][4].get_center(), q1_s1[0][3].get_center()+q1_s1[0][7].get_center()+UP*0.15, color=GREEN)
        carrow2 = CurvedArrow(q1_s1[0][3].get_center(), q1_s1[0][4].get_center(), color=RED)
        q1_s1c = q1_s1.copy()
        self.add(q1_s1c)
        self.play(Write(carrow2))
        self.wait()
        self.play(FadeOut(carrow2))
        self.play(TransformMatchingTex(q1_s1, q1_s2))
        self.wait()
        self.play(Write(carrow1))
        self.wait()
        self.play(FadeOut(carrow1))
        self.play(Transform(q1_s1c, q1_s3))
        self.wait()
        s3l = Tex("Unstable Product").next_to(q1_s3, DOWN)
        s2l = Tex("Most Stable Product").next_to(q1_s2, DOWN)
        self.play(Write(s2l), Write(s3l))
        self.play(FadeOut(VGroup(q1_s3, s3l), shift=RIGHT*2))
        self.play(VGroup(q1_s2, s2l).animate.shift(RIGHT*3))
        self.wait()
        self.play(FadeOut(VGroup(q1_s2, s2l)))

        self.wait()
        q1_s1 = Tex(r"\chemfig{*4([:45]--(-\oplus)--)}", tex_template=template).set_stroke(WHITE, 2)
        self.play(Write(q1_s1))
        self.wait()
        q1_s2 = Tex(r"\chemfig{*5([:18]---\oplus--)}", tex_template=template).set_stroke(WHITE, 2)
        carrow1 = CurvedArrow(q1_s1[0][1].get_center(), q1_s1[0][2].get_center(), color=GREEN)
        self.play(Write(carrow1))
        self.wait()
        self.play(FadeOut(carrow1))
        self.play(Transform(q1_s1, q1_s2))
        self.wait()
        self.play(FadeOut(q1_s2))
        q1_s1 = Tex(r"\chemfig{*6(----([:30]-\oplus)([:150]-)--)}", tex_template=template).set_stroke(WHITE, 2)
        self.play(Write(q1_s1))
        self.wait()
        q1_s2 = Tex(r"\chemfig{*5([:18]---\oplus(--[::60])--)}", tex_template=template).shift(LEFT*3).set_stroke(WHITE, 2)
        q1_s3 = Tex(r"\chemfig{*7([:-12.8]-----(-\oplus)--)}", tex_template=template).set_stroke(WHITE, 2).shift(RIGHT*3)
        carrow1 = CurvedArrow(q1_s1[0][4].get_center(), q1_s1[0][3].get_center()+q1_s1[0][7].get_center()+UP*0.15, color=GREEN)
        carrow2 = CurvedArrow(q1_s1[0][3].get_center(), q1_s1[0][4].get_center(), color=RED)
        q1_s1c = q1_s1.copy()
        self.add(q1_s1c)
        self.play(Write(carrow2))
        self.wait()
        self.play(FadeOut(carrow2))
        self.play(Transform(q1_s1, q1_s3))
        self.wait()
        self.play(Write(carrow1))
        self.wait()
        self.play(FadeOut(carrow1))
        self.play(Transform(q1_s1c, q1_s2))
        self.wait()
        s3l = Tex("Unstable Product").next_to(q1_s3, DOWN)
        s2l = Tex("Most stable Product").next_to(q1_s2, DOWN)
        self.play(Write(s2l), Write(s3l))
        self.play(FadeOut(VGroup(q1_s3, s3l), shift=RIGHT*2))
        self.play(VGroup(q1_s2, s2l).animate.shift(RIGHT*3))
        self.wait()
        self.play(FadeOut(VGroup(q1_s2, q1_s3)))

        q1_s1 = Tex(r"\chemfig{*5([:18]---([:150]-\charge{135=\:,-135=\:}{O}H)([:30]-\chemabove{C}{\oplus}H_2)--)}", tex_template=template).set_stroke(WHITE, 2)
        self.play(Write(q1_s1))
        labels = self.label(q1_s1[0], width=0.1).set_z_index(999)
        self.play(Write(labels)
        self.wait()


    
    def circled_tex_string(self, tex):
        return r"\raisebox{.5pt}{\textcircled{\raisebox{-.9pt} {"+str(tex)+r"}}}"

    def label(self, mob, width=0.07):
        n = VGroup()
        for element,index in zip(mob,range(len(mob))):
            i = Text(f"{index}",color=RED).set_width(width)
            i.next_to(element,UP,buff=0)
            n.add(i)
        return n
    

class Question2(MovingCameraScene):
    def construct(self):
        pass
```

The animation(Question1) turns out to be like [this](https://youtu.be/Yabt9M7414Y)

What I tried:

- Using the `--flush_cache` command line argument
- Clearing cache by deleting the Question1 folder in Partial movie files folder
- Trying to render with code from the file history when everything was working properly
- Searching for similar questions on the web